# SELECT previous year up to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, getdate

I have a table which has a Start Date column for example:

```
Start Date
2015/01/05
2015/02/08
2016/01/10
2017/02/10
etc...
```

I am trying to put into my `WHERE` clause to select all records where it is one year prior based on the current `GETDATE()`.

For example, if today is July 2019 and I run the query, I'd like for it to run and give me Start Dates starting from July of 2018 up until June of 2019. And if I run it for August of 2019, I'd like for it to show Start Dates from August of 2018 up until July of 2019, and so on. Basically up until the month before of the current date.

Currently I have this in my `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE start_date between DATEADD(YEAR,-1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

but this appears I believe to get just one year prior up until the current date exact.

Is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: What you are doing is ok. Double check your output.

Comment: If I am trying to get it to where it gets up until the month prior to the GETDATE(), do I  need to adjust the second GETDATE() to DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) ?

Comment: What you are doing is ok. Another thing is if you want to cover July from 1st 2018 to July 1st 2019. If not so, your query is correct.

Comment: It's a matter  of tacking together the correct functions. Like these examples: http://zarez.net/?p=2462

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is your requirement:

```
WHERE start_date BETWEEN
  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) 
  AND
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

With:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
```

you get the 1st day of current month in last year.
With:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

you get the last Day of previous month.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b278dec19979af1948dc2e309d242227).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datefromparts()` in SQL Server:

```
where start_date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1) and
      start_date < datefromparts(year(getdate() - 1, month(getdate()), day(getdate())
```